# Problems with installation stuck on 5 dot screen

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS from official site, as well as Linux Mint 18 from its official site, and both installations get stuck at loading installation screen (the one with 5 dots).

I have tried installation from 2 different USB sticks, and thinking that might be the issue i have tried to install from DVD and that didn't resolve the issue for both setups, i have also tried changing some of the options i have in BIOS (like "Launch CSM" and boot sequence and so on, nothing worked, always stuck at same 5 dots screen. Solutions with trying 2.0 port didn't work, and i can't find solution for this issue. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

How long have you left it there? On my computer it takes several minutes (probably 2-3 at least) to complete the 5 dot screen. Perhaps just leave it there for a half hour and see how it goes.

Comment: Tried that too, left it for an hour and nothing changed... Laptop wasn't even making a sound for the duration, so i am assuming it did nothing.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'm assuming you are using the 64bit version, yes? What are your machines specs. It may be an issue where it can't handle the 64 bit version properly.

Comment: 64 bit yes, its Asus from x553MA series, what specs exactly should i give you?

Comment: Processor and RAM would be the most important, as that would determine whether or not it can handle 64 bit or 32 bit.

Comment: Intel Pentium quad core N3540 2.16 GHz, and ram is 4 gb, currently running 64 bit windows 10.